# Unexpected results when using {redirect=404} and template layouts

Tags: 404, error-pages, template-layouts

It appears that when using the [recommended method](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/404pages.html#examples) of `{if no_results}{redirect=404}{/if}` in a template that uses the template layout feature, it duplicates the layout, if a layout is also used on the actual 404 template. The 404 template lives at `errors/404` it includes the following:

**errors/404 template**

```
{layout="_layouts/master}
404 Error Content Here
```

When viewing a normal page that 404s (sitename.com/pagedoesntexist) it works as expected.

**_layouts/master template**

```
{layout="_layouts/_global}
   {embed="_embeds/header"}
     {layout:contents}
   {embed="_embeds/footer"}
```

On instances that do not work as expected it's set up like the following:

**Sample template using the 404 redirect tag**

```
{layout="_layouts/master}
{exp:channel:entries}
   Content Here

   {if no_results}
     {redirect=404}
   {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This results in the file rendering the master layout twice (double header + footer in my instance) because the `{redirect=404}` tag is essentially copying the results of the /errors/404 template into the template that contains no results instead of displaying the 404 page as usual.

Is there a way around this bug, preferably that doesn't require enabling php in templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in EE 2.9.0: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20471/site-index-template-is-rendered-after-the-404-template

The fix from that thread:

Open system/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php and find this code on line 2236:

```
ee()->output->out_type = "404";
ee()->output->set_output($out);
ee()->output->_display();
```

And REPLACE it with this:

```
ee()->output->out_type = "404";
ee()->output->set_output($out);
ee()->output->_display();
exit;
```