# 404 not rendering correctly when using template layouts

Tags: 404, parsing, layouts

I'm finding in EE 2.10.1 that if I try to check for the presence of a valid category in a URL using Low Seg2Cat and then perform a redirect on error that when the 404 template is rendered it inherits the layout and layout variables specified beneath the redirect in the original template:

```
{if !segment_3_category_id}
{redirect="404"}
{/if}
{layout="global/.layout_2col"}
```

This doesn't appear to be a problem when not using layouts. It's as if the layout is processed before the redirect and then the content of the 404 template is inserted 'into' the layout of the page/url which generated the 404.

I'm thinking this could possibly be related to [Unexpected results when using {redirect=404} and template layouts](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25145/unexpected-results-when-using-redirect-404-and-template-layouts) but as I'm using 2.10.1 the patch associated with that is already applied.

:?